# JSON to JAXB XML KEY VALUE attributes

Tags: json, xml, soap, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a requirement to convert the Rest Dynamic JSon String to XML with  key and  value attributes and  form the Jaxb Saop request.

Below is the Sample XMl format i am looking.

```
<emailData key1='value1' key2='valu2' key3='value3'></emailData>
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: This is the XMl format i am looking. <data key1='value1' key2='value2' key3='value3'/>

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

What exactly is your problem?
Do you have an [MCVE] you could post?
And how is [tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin] relevant here?
What do you want to implement? You've thrown in a few keywords like JSON, JAXB, XML etc. What do you get as input and what do you want to produce as output?

Comment: Underscore-java library has static method U.jsonToXml(json).